# Long exact sequence of cohomology

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, homology-cohomology, group-actions

I was reading about cohomology and [long exact sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_cohomology#Long_exact_sequence_of_cohomology). I found that

> Given $$0 \to L \to M \to N \to 0$$ is a short exact sequence of $G$- modules, then a there exists a long exact sequence is defined as
>   $$0\longrightarrow L^G \longrightarrow M^G \longrightarrow N^G \overset{\delta^0}{\longrightarrow} H^1(G,L) \longrightarrow H^1(G,M) \longrightarrow H^1(G,N) \overset{\delta^1}{\longrightarrow} H^2(G,L)\longrightarrow \cdots$$
>   and the so-called connecting homomorphism is:
>   $$\delta^n : H^n (G,N) \to H^{n+1}(G, L)$$

**My specific question is for $n=1$** :

> Is there any explicit description of the map
>   $$\delta^1 : H^1 (G,N) \to H^{2}(G, L)$$

I have found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_cohomology#Long_exact_sequence_of_cohomology) that:

> The description of the map $\delta^n$ is given as:
>
> If $c \in H^n(G, N)$ is represented by an $n$-cocycle $\phi: G^n \to N$ then $\delta^n(c)$ is $d^n(\varphi)$ where $\varphi$ is an $n$-cochain $G^n \to M$ "lifting" $\phi$ via surjective map $M\to N$ and $d^n$ is defined ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_cohomology#Cochain_complexes)) as 
>   $$\left(d^{n+1}\varphi\right) (g_1, \ldots, g_{n+1}) = g_1 \varphi(g_2, \dots, g_{n+1}) + \sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^i \varphi \left (g_1,\ldots, g_{i-1}, g_i g_{i+1}, \ldots, g_{n+1} \right ) + (-1)^{n+1}\varphi(g_1,\ldots, g_n)$$

But from the above description is it seems that $d^n(\varphi) : G^{n+1}\to M$ but we need that $\delta^n(c) : G^{n+1}\to L$, so what I am actually missing here?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If one regards $L$ as a submodule of $M$, then the image of the map in your last formula (a priori in $M$) is contained in $L$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Thanks. This should be the case I also thought but I am still confused why this is true. Can you please help me?

Comment: If you apply $\pi:M\to N$ to that formula, you get the coboundary of $\varphi$ in $N$, which is zero since by assumption $\phi$ is a cocycle.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I partially get that. Thanks.  If the the image in N is zero then it is in the kernel and so in the image of L. True, I understand. But last question, sorry, why the image under $\pi$ is zero, I mean why $\phi$ is cocylce implies the zero image? Sorry again

Comment: By definition, a cocycle is a cochain with coboundary zero.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Thanks. Just to be clear sorry, say $n=1$, then  $\pi\ocirc d^1 = 0 \in N$ right? and this is because $\pi\ocirc d^1$ gives a cochain from a cocycle and thus the coboundary is zero?